# How do I extract a bunch of lines from one .txt file and add them to another?

Tags: python, loops, file-handling

https://repl.it/join/zlkssoum-muhammadqadeer

```
file = open("Teacher Database.txt", "r")

lines = file.readlines()

for i in range(15, 28):
 KM = open("Karen McAskill.txt", "a")
 KM.write(lines[i])
 KM.close()
```

I have a main database file but I want to take information from that main file and add it into 5 separate smaller files. I've tried using a for loop but each time I run the program, the information just duplicates into the smaller files. I want to take the information and write it just once into the smaller file.

Comment: Its 5 files and then its just "the smaller file". Your code opens one file multiple times in append mode, so we'd expect lines 15 to 27 to duplicate each time the script is run. How many files do you want? What should be put into them? Should the program erase the files each time its run or append into existing files?

Comment: Also, add any example data to the question, not a external link. Especially not one that requires an account and login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using line numbers you can split the file data and then you can write the data to files. This code will automatically create the file with the person Name.

```
with open("Teacher Database.txt") as fp:
    for person in fp.read().split('Name: '):
        if person.strip():
            file_name = person.split('\n', 1)[0] + '.txt'
            with open(file_name, 'a') as fw:
                fw.write('Name: ' + person)
```

Comment: Do you know why it creates an extra file called .txt which just has "Name: " stored in it. Is there a way we can avoid it? Also if you could please explain the third line of code it would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: @MAQdaCODER third line is creating the output file name

Comment: @MAQdaCODER fixed the creation of `.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the lines from the original file, you can open it again in write mode and write the lines you want to keep back to it and write the rest to another file.

```
file = open("Teacher Database.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file = open("Teacher Database.txt", "w")

KM = open("Karen McAskill.txt", "a")

for i in range(len(lines)):
 if i >= 25 and i <= 28:
  # the lines you want to move
  KM.write(lines[i])
 else:
  # the lines you want to keep
  file.write(lines[i)
KM.close()
file.close()
```

You can add more branching logic to move to other files.